# Are the statements attributed to Donald Trump and his sons about Russian connections accurately quoted?

Tags: quotes, donald-trump

[Holly O'Reilly](https://hollyfigueroaoreilly.com/) posted [an image](https://twitter.com/AynRandPaulRyan/status/861715228387442688) on twitter that gives the following quotes:

> "I have nothing to do with Russia - no deals, no loans, no nothing." -- Donald Trump
>
> "Russians make up a pretty disproportionate cross-section of a lot of our assets. We see a lot of money pouring in from Russia." -- Donald Trump Jr.
>
> "Well, we don't rely on American banks. We have all the funding we need out of Russia." -- Eric Trump

Are the statements attributed to Trump and his sons accurately quoted?

Comment: Mohammed, please ask clearly notable questions. Take the time to format them properly. Don't put gigantic images. You should know better than  this.

Comment: I think the claim, that the sons said those things, is notable: because I've seen those quotes before, on Twitter.

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin: Before you gave the source, there was nothing "clearly noteable" about this claim. You could just as well have composed the image yourself.

Comment: I spelled out the quotes and removed the image entirely. It's linked for those who are interested, and for this site only the text actually matters.

Comment: @DevSolar a quick google image search for the image returns a lot of results which make it notable.

Comment: But it's up to you to *establish* noteability. We shouldn't have to google around to check for it.

Comment: As [mentioned here](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3974/2703), if someone questions whether it's notable, then it's up to you to edit the question to state why you think it's notable.

Comment: @Sklivvz: With the links in place, the question should be reopened as noteable (posted by a celebrity, and apparently somewhat widespread as per ChrisW's comment).

Comment: @CPerkins - As far as I can tell, that's not from a Time interview, but rather a New York real estate conference (at least, according to [this Time article](http://time.com/4629308/donald-trump-business-deals-world-map/)). Not sure whether those comments were recorded.

Comment: @dan-klasson Fam, I brought it up because i found it entertaining. I don't care about you downvotes.

Answer (score 10):

The first quote is from this [tweet by Trump](https://twitter.com/realdonaldtrump/status/819159806489591809?lang=en) from the 11th of January 2017:

> Russia has never tried to use leverage over me. I HAVE NOTHING TO DO WITH RUSSIA - NO DEALS, NO LOANS, NO NOTHING!

The source of the second quote is this [eturbonews.com](http://www.eturbonews.com/5008/executive-talk-donald-trump-jr-bullish-russia-and-few-emerging-ma) article from 2008 about remarks from Trump Jr. at the Cityscape USA Bridges U.S. and Emerging Real Estate Markets Conference:

> “And in terms of high-end product influx into the US, Russians make up a pretty disproportionate cross-section of a lot of our assets; say in Dubai, and certainly with our project in SoHo and anywhere in New York. We see a lot of money pouring in from Russia. There’s indeed a lot of money coming for new-builds and resale reflecting a trend in the Russian economy and, of course, the weak dollar versus the ruble,” he said.

I don't see a reason for them to make this up in 2008, but there does not seem to be audio recording of this, nor are there other sources from the time that reported about this. One [other](http://www.worldpropertyjournal.com/international-markets/residential-real-estate/cityscape-usa-dubai-nakheel-real-estate-conference-12.php) website reported about the conference and Trump Jr., but does not contain the quote or any other statements made by Trump Jr. regarding Russia.

The source for the third quote is James Dodson - a writer focusing on golf - in an interview with WBUR, in which he claims that Eric Trump said this in a [private conversation](http://www.wbur.org/onlyagame/2017/05/05/james-dodson-donald-trump-golf) in 2013. Eric Trump [denies](http://www.wbur.org/onlyagame/2017/05/08/eric-trump-russia-golf-course-funding) this. There is no way of knowing whose version of events is correct.